# Accessing Private Members Of Enum Variable?

Tags: java, variables, enums

I was looking at a simple Enum example to try and brush up my skills and I noticed something that at least through up a red flag for me as I don't understand why it's allowed.

Here is a copy of the enum I was looking at:

```
public enum GameDuration {
    Short("30"), Medium("45"), Long("60");

    private GameDuration(String minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    private String minutes;

    public String getMinutes() {
        return this.minutes;
    }

    public static GameDuration fromMinutes(String minutes) {
        if (minutes != null) {
            for (GameDuration g : GameDuration.values()) {
                if (minutes.equalsIgnoreCase(g.minutes)) {
                    return g;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The part I don't understand is in the *fromMinutes* method and pasted below:

```
if (minutes.equalsIgnoreCase(g.minutes)) {
```

the minutes field in the enum is marked as private so how can it be accessed directly from the variable g?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `fromMinutes(...)` is located inside of the GameDuration class, and so private variables and methods of the class are accessible to it.

Comment: oh snap i didn't notice.. sorry it's late. :) even though it's static?

Comment: @JanTacci: even though it is static (as your compiler is already telling you).

Comment: k got it i should have noticed that sooner :)

Comment: @JanTacci: no problem. Glad you've figured it out.